# How to create an animation like the connections in Interface Builder (thin blue line)? Quartz 2D?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, quartz-2d

Never worked with graphics frameworks. 
Suppose I can do event handling "pressed" button (picture) and link it to some other target element of which will be introduced at this point the mouse.
But how do the animation which exists until the mouse button is pressed and is visible over all forms? What is the starting point? What frameworks, class and methods?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a CAShapeLayer on top of the window's layer, and setting it up to stroke a thin blue line. Then you can install a CGPath that's just a line, and change the path as the user drags with the mouse. You could either use a very short duration animation, or use a CATransaction to change the path without animation so it updates as fast as possible.

Comment: I'll try, but I think it will not be the same. In Interface Builder Connect line can be displayed outside of the form and move around the screen.